# Common webViewDidStartLoad by category

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

I think implement completely same method to every viewController with UIWebView (and delegate=self)is not smart. So tried to setup common loading method with all UIWebView. But it did not work. 
Is it wrong to achieve with category?

**UIWebView+Loading.m**

```
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView*)webView
{ 
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
}
```

**ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "UIWebView+Loading.h"

//abbr...

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIWebView *someWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    someWebView.delegate = self;

    //and HTTP request
    NSURLRequest *req = (abbr);
    [someWebView loadRequest:req];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `webViewDidStartLoad:` is not being called because it is a part of `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol, not a method of `UIWebView` class itself. You have to implement it in your **ViewController.m** file.

Also, you may want to read about [delegation pattern in iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html).

Comment: I understand making category with UIWebView is wrong. And how can I achieve it? I think implement completely same method to every viewController with UIWebView (and delegate=self)is not smart. I will read delegation pattern, thanks.

Comment: If you have more view controllers containing UIWebView, you can make a  superclass for them (UIViewControllerWithWebView) and implement UIWebViewDelegate methods in it.

Answer (score 0):

Dont need a category like UIWebView+Loading.m for this purpose.

The webview delegate methods will get executed when the loading stats and the delegate method

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"Started loading");
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"Finshed loading");
}
```

will get executed.The code you written is enough.Since the delegate is set to self .In the viewcontroller define these methods and thats it .You will have it working

Comment: Thanks, but i want to make a common UIWebView(or UIWebViewDelegate) class that "webViewDidStartLoad" is pre-set.